# How can I create a link to an outline attachment in Org mode?

Tags: org-mode, hyperlinks, attachment

I am trying to create links within the body of an outline to files that are attached to that outline  using the [guidance in the documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Attachment-links.html)

```
***** Test outline                                                    :ATTACH:
      :PROPERTIES:
      :ID:       385a7ddd-0bb9-478c-9b3c-9bd87f14b344
      :Attachments: test-file
      :END:

[[attachment:test-file]]
```

I realise my example is not identical to the docs but the item in the docs doesn't seem to have an attachment.  When I click on my resulting link I get a dialog "No match - create this as a new heading?" which is exactly the behaviour for any internal link for which no heading matches i.e. it doesn't seem to be interpreting this as an attachment link. If I click 'Yes' it gives me a new heading `attachment:test-file`

What am I doing wrong? How can you create a link to an outline attachment?

Comment: Have you changed any of the defaults? If not, have you created a `data/` directory in the same place where the Org mode file  is? Is there a subdirectory `38/` under `data/`? Is there a subdirectory `5a7ddd-0bb9-478c-9b3c-9bd87f14b344/` under `data/38/`? Is there a file `test-file` under `data/38/5a7ddd-0bb9-478c-9b3c-9bd87f14b344`? Is the file readable? AFAIK, `org-attach` does not add an `Attachments` property, so who added that? But if you created that `data/` directory and then did `C-c C-a a` giving it an existing file, then the link should work (and it does for me, FWIW).

Comment: If you evaluate this in your `*scratch*` buffer: `(assoc "attachment" org-link-parameters)` what does it return?

Answer (score 1):

The link is dispatched to a wrong handler, which means your `org-attach` package is
probably not loaded yet. You can verify it by inspecting the `org-link-parameters` variable to
check whether the `attachment` link type is present: evaluate `(assoc "attachment" org-link-parameters)` - if it returns `nil`, that means that `org-attach` is not loaded yet. You can also check by asking for help on one of its functions, e.g. `C-h f org-attach`: the doc string will say `[Arg list not available until function definition is loaded.]` in that case.

You can just add:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (require ‘org-attach))
```

to your init file (and restart emacs), so that all of the features that `org-attach` provides will always be available. Or
invoke one of its autoload functions like `org-attach` or `org-attach-dired-to-subtree` *before* you try to follow an `attachment` link: that will trigger the autoload of the file which will add the `attachment` type to `org-link-parameters` and allow such links to be resolved properly.